# How to Delete JWT authorized Data using ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, e-commerce, express-jwt

I'm using JWT to access control of the express and React ecommerce application. but i dont have any idea about how to
delete the logged user in the application. I have already tried arrow function and button onclick handler on this matter. You can find my express code below.

```
router.delete("/delete", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const deletedU = await U.findByIdAndDelete(req.U);
    res.json(deletedU);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

```
<button className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs" onClick={Delete}>Delete</button>
```

Above snippet contains the react code for button onClick handler. If you have suggestions please answer.Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the user ? You should invalidate the JWT token for the user. And a service which should always validate the token whenever the user want to perform some action.

Comment: #prasad I need to remove that selected user from the database.I have used Invalidating token for the logout process  of the user

Comment: await U.findByIdAndDelete(req.U) --> are you sure req.U will contain the userId ? how are you passing the userId in the route ?

Comment: res.json({
      token,
      U: {
        id: U._id } im passing It from login it contain all the other data in the U but when im using ID to delete it wont work am i doing it wrong way?

Comment: How do you call this router function --? router.delete ? what do you pass as a param ? you should pass in the request the userId. Then only req object will have the userId

Comment: @BrijeshPrasad I have called this router function as `router.delete` then I'm getting U data when someone login. Using Token. I believe i can get data from the `res.json({ Token and U })` using this `{userData.U.UserName}` I'm getting all the data like name and Email but i don't know why i can't  pass the  Id  in to Delete 'router.delete("/delete", auth, async (req, res) => { '

Answer (score 0):

You can pass id in your router as below :

```
router.delete('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
 let id = req.params.id;
  //Call your delete logic here.

});
```

In order to execute the above route you should do

`{yourApi}/delete/123` --> where 123 is the id of the user